# Displaying multiple JLabels on the same frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Picture");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  display = new JPanel();      
if(event.getSource().equals(birthday)){
    background = new JLabel(bday);
    display.add(background);

  }
  else if(event.getSource().equals(cake)){
    picture = new JLabel(pastry, SwingConstants.LEFT);
    display.add(picture);
  }
  else if(event.getSource().equals(input)){
    word = new JLabel(text);
    word.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    word.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    display.add(word);
  }
  frame.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(450, 350));
  frame.getContentPane().add(display);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is part of an ActionListener class inside my standalone class. I had a comboBox/cardLayout. So when I clicked a button (cake) from one comboBox label, and another button (birthday) from another another comboxBox label, two frames appeared. I want the stuff to be on the SAME frame, but I couldn't figure out how to do so.

Comment: This depends, what is triggering the action performed??

Comment: So, you just want to know how to get 2 JLabels on the same JPanel?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, when you clicked a button, one JLabel supposed to pop up in a frame (frame2). Now, the button itself is contained in a frame(frame1) already. So what I've done is to create another frame in my standalone. What I've been trying to do is that when I clicked another button on frame1, another JLabel will be displayed on frame2. But I've been getting that label on another frame (frame3). :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather the creating new instance of the frame each time the action perform method is called, you need to create a single shared instance...

[image]

```
public class OneFrameToRuleThemAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OneFrameToRuleThemAll();
    }

    public OneFrameToRuleThemAll() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JFrame frame;

        private static final String FRUIT[] = new String[] {
            "Banana",
            "Apple",
            "Manga",
            "Pear"
        };

        public TestPane() {

            JButton button = new JButton("Fruit");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (frame == null) {
                        frame = new JFrame("Fruits basket");
                        frame.setSize(100, 200);
                        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(TestPane.this);
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }

                    int index = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (FRUIT.length - 1));
                    frame.add(new JLabel(FRUIT[index]));
                    frame.getContentPane().validate();

                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(button);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! However, I'm afraid I'm a bit confused about your solution (relatively new to GUI...) I have a standalone class that contains buttons and stuff, and a driver that displays that frame. However, I want to enable another frame to pop up when I click a button, that frame I have it defined in the ActionListener class. When I click another button though, another frame pops up, containing different stuff. I want the content of that frame to be contained in the same frame as the first button....

Comment: Yeah, which is basically what my example does.  Rather then creating a new `JFrame` each time `actionPerformed` is called, you would create a single instance and use.  In my example I've used a lazy loading approach, but you could just as easily create the frame when the class is instantiated, but that does allocate memory you're not really using...

Comment: So should I declare and instantiate a frame in the constructor of my standalone?? o-o I've been trying that..and for some reasons Java is throwing me run time errors..

Comment: Ok so I just declared and instantiated a frame in my constructor and added the panel in my actionPerformed...no error, just that the second frame refused to show up anything when I clicked a button...